# Array Only Returning Most Recent Input

Tags: java, arrays, do-while

So im trying to pass a array as a parameter to a class but its only showing the most recent objects inputs when i print to screen

```
            for (int j=0;j<5;j++) {
                do {
                    System.out.print("Enter Test Score " +(j+1)+" between 0-100 : ");
                    score = sc.nextInt();
                    sc.nextLine();
                }while(score<0||score>100);
                ts[j] = score;
            }

          s.setTestScore(ts);
          System.out.println("");
```

This is how it should have been done, i wasnt passing it correctly to the method it should have been position in array and score where i was only passing the most recent score repeatedly

```
        for (int j=0;j<5;j++) {
            //Prints this message to the screen to make sure score is between 0-100
            do {
                System.out.print("Enter Test Score " +(j+1)+" between 0-100 : ");
                score = sc.nextInt();
                sc.nextLine();
            }while(score<0||score>100);

            s.setTestScore(j,score);
        }
```

when i pass name and id it works using the exact same system s.set(nameofmethod)

```
    void setTestScore(int[] test) {
       this.test = test;
    }
    int[] getTests() {
       return test;
    }
```

i then pass test to a method to calculate and it just prints out pass/fail for each object created regardless of scores

```
    void calculateResult() {
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
        sum += test[i];
    }
    sum = sum/numTests;
    if(sum<40) {
        grade = "Fail";
    }
    else {
        grade = "Pass";
    }

    System.out.println(grade);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "only showing the most recent objects"? Also this doesn't answer your question, but your while loop only accepts scores that are negative or greater than 100, but your input print says enter a score between 0 and 100.  If you want that, you need to change the loop to `score >= 0 || score <= 100`

Comment: @AustinAdams Actually, it's looping while the score is negative or greater than 100, so it only accepts input between 1 and 100 (after which it exits the input loop).

Comment: @azurefrog Yeah you're right, I misread the code

Comment: @AustinAdams no buddy my input takes scores correctly it repeats while the number is less than 0 or greater than 100

Comment: Yeah you're right, sorry I just misread your code.  Could you explain what the problem you're having is though? Do you mean that the array only contains the most recent value entered?

Comment: @AustinAdams i added a picture, i feel its something really stupid as i checked what was being passed into the student class from the driver class and it was fine

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question does not conform with the community's guidelines, and will soon be closed by a moderator. You should edit it appropriately if you expect to get any answers. Good questions usually include: **A desired outcome or result**, **What you have tried so far to solve your problem** and more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you either need to run calculateResult after you enter in the test scores for each student, or you need to have some sort of hash of arrays to keep track of which array of test scores belongs to which student.  Since you only have a single array `test[]`, the scores for student id 5 are overwritten by the scores for student id 77.  You can try something like this:

```
for (int j=0;j<5;j++) {
  do {
    System.out.print("Enter Test Score " +(j+1)+" between 0-100 : ");
    score = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
  }while(score<0||score>100);
  ts[j] = score;
}

 s.setTestScore(ts);
 s.calculateResult();
 System.out.println("");
```

Comment: This would better be suited as a comment, not an answer. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I edited my response to include a code snippet for what he could try

Comment: But each Student object contains its own test array.  why would it assign name, id, etc but now the test array

Comment: Could you edit your question with more code snippets to get a better context of what is going on? The fact that this is a Student object with its own name, id, and array of tests is not clear reading your question.

Comment: @AustinAdams so i place the calculateresult where you say to it does work. but i wish to call it in the like the picture i printed as thats the requirements for the assignment. im using inheritance and overriding a method hence why i have undergrad and postgrad. i actually wish to calculate the results in the postgrad/undergrad but i figured id getting it working in the superclass first

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code I can't say exactly what the problem is.  However I guess you can add a field to your class called `pass_fail` or something.  Then you can make `calculateResult` return the value "Pass" or "Fail" and set your field after the loop using `this.pass_fail = calculateResult();`  You would need to change the return value of `calculateResult` from `void` to `String` if you did it that way.

Comment: @AustinAdams ya buddy i would do that, thats the way i had thought it should be done but its states its a void method. Thanks for the help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202174/discussion-between-aidan-ward-and-austin-adams).